# How to combine data from multiple cells into one cell in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel

When converting data from a text file into excel, I was able to separate the data into columns using the Delimited tab function.  However, some data was split into two columns.  As a result, I now have data in multiple cells for each row.  I am able use a simple formula to concatenate such as:
=A1&B1

However, there is no space between the data after it is combined.  How do I revise the formula to create a space between the data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following instead:
=CONCATENATE(A1&" "&B1)
" " adds a space inbetween two text you will be able to find a space between the concatenated string.

Answer (score 1):

Try using  `=A1&" "&B1`

You can use constants in such formulae